# How to make SetCursorPos and/or SendInput work in a VM?

Tags: winapi, virtual-machine

I have a program that uses SetCursorPos to position the cursor.  The program operates as it is supposed to when running on real hardware but, when running in a VM (VMware workstation 10.0.7) it doesn't work.   The cursor does not move.  I tried using SendInput instead (the syscall it makes is different, because of that, I thought it might work), the result is the same as with SetCursorPos, it works on real hardware, does not work when running in a VM.

The question is: does anyone know if either SetCursorPos or SendInput can be made to work in a VM and if yes, how ?  Any other way to position the cursor at a specific place that works in a VM would be welcome as well.

Thank you for your help.

For anyone who cares to try, here is some of the code I've tried.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

program ConsoleSetCursorPos;

uses
  Windows
  ;

function GetConsoleWindow : HWND; stdcall; external kernel32;

procedure DoIt;
var
  ConsoleWindow   : HWND;
  ClientRect      : TRECT;

  CursorPosRetVal : BOOL;
  LastError       : dword;

  Desktop         : HDESK;

begin
  // the code below is not normally necessary - for testing only

  Desktop       := OpenInputDesktop(0, false, WINSTA_WRITEATTRIBUTES);
  LastError     := GetLastError;

  writeln;
  writeln('From OpenInputDesktop');
  writeln('Last error (decimal) : ', LastError);

  if Desktop = 0 then
  begin
    writeln('Program terminated due to OpenInputDesktop failure');
    halt(255);
  end;

  if not SetThreadDesktop(Desktop) then
  begin
    writeln('Program terminated due to SetThreadDesktop failure');
    halt(255);
  end;

  writeln;

  // end of normally unnecessary code

  SetLastError(0);
  ConsoleWindow := GetConsoleWindow;

  GetClientRect(ConsoleWindow, ClientRect);

  ClientToScreen(ConsoleWindow, ClientRect.TopLeft);

  CursorPosRetVal := SetCursorPos(ClientRect.Left, ClientRect.Top);
  LastError       := GetLastError;

  if not CursorPosRetVal
  then writeln('SetCursorPos returned false (failed)')
  else writeln('SetCursorPos returned true  (succeeded)');

  writeln('Last error (decimal) : ', LastError);

  if Desktop <> 0 then CloseDesktop(Desktop);
end;

begin
  DoIt;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

As the remarks on [SetCursorPos doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursorpos):

> The cursor is a shared resource. A window should move the cursor only
>   when the cursor is in the window's client area.
>
> The calling process must have WINSTA_WRITEATTRIBUTES access to the
>   window station.
>
> The input desktop must be the current desktop when you call
>   SetCursorPos. Call [OpenInputDesktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-openinputdesktop) to determine whether the current
>   desktop is the input desktop. If it is not, call [SetThreadDesktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setthreaddesktop) with
>   the HDESK returned by OpenInputDesktop to switch to that desktop.

Or you can take the same try to un-installed the mouse driver from the VM as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969031/programaticly-move-mouse-in-vmware-c-sharp).

Comment: I read the remarks on SetCursorPos and, it is because of those remarks I added calls to OpenInputDesktop and SetThreadDesktop which succeeded but did not make any difference when running under VMware workstation.  The answer you linked to isn't practical.  It is not reasonable to expect a user to uninstall standard VMware drivers to make an application work but, your linking to it leads me to believe that under VMware, it is likely that neither SetCursorPos nor SendInput operate as they should.  Unintentionally, it might be a simple way of determining if software is running in a VM.